# sp_executesql returning different results than direct query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following two queries are returning different results.   I understand the difference has to do with the way the time portions of the dates are being handled, but why is it working this way?

```
// QUERY ONE
select top 3 OrderDate
from Orders
where OrderDate >= '2013-11-01 04:00'
and OrderDate <= '2013-11-30 05:00'
order by OrderDate

// RESULTS
// 2013-11-01
// 2013-11-01
// 2013-11-01

// QUERY TWO
exec sp_executesql
    N'select top 3 OrderDate
      from Orders
      where OrderDate >= @p__linq__0
      and OrderDate <= @p__linq__1
      order by OrderDate',
    N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',
    @p__linq__0='2013-11-01T04:00:00',
    @p__linq__1='2013-11-30T05:00:00'

// RESULTS
// 2013-11-02
// 2013-11-02
// 2013-11-02
```

UPDATE

If I change the types of the parameters passed to sp_executesql to 'date' instead of 'datetime', the results are the same.

```
// QUERY THREE
exec sp_executesql
N'select top 3 OrderDate
  from Orders
  where OrderDate >= @p__linq__0
  and OrderDate <= @p__linq__1
  order by OrderDate',
N'@p__linq__0 date,@p__linq__1 date',
@p__linq__0='2013-11-01T04:00:00',
@p__linq__1='2013-11-30T05:00:00'

// RESULTS
// 2013-11-01
// 2013-11-01
// 2013-11-01
```

Comment: What happens if you pass parameters as simple `datetime` ?

Comment: What results does the first query return if you use the datatypes from the second?

Comment: Can you post some or all of the data the query is being run against? Table structure with column type might help, too. (I want to know why the 11/2 data did not get returned by the first query.)

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I'm getting the same results if I pass the parameters as simple datetime.

Comment: @HABO - What do you mean by using the datatypes from the second?

Comment: Well, they're different. Why does the hard-coded value not have a T but the parameterized ones do?

Comment: @PhilipKelley OrderDate column is of type Date.

Comment: Also if OrderDate is a DATE, why are you including time at all in any of your values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Data type precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) is taking the data in your table, which starts as a date, and compares it as a datetime2(7). So your dynamic SQL version is actually running this:

```
WHERE column_as_datetime2 >= @parameter_as_datetime2
```

So, since `2013-11-01 00:00:00.0000000` is *not* greater than or equal to `2013-11-01 04:00:00.0000000`, the rows from November 1st are left out.

The most practical solution is to use `DATE` parameters (preferred, since the parameters should match the underlying data type, after all), and/or stop passing time values along with them. Try these:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders(OrderDate DATE);

INSERT dbo.Orders VALUES('2013-11-01'),('2013-11-01'),('2013-11-01'),
  ('2013-11-02'),('2013-11-02'),('2013-11-02');

exec sp_executesql N'select top 3 OrderDate
      from Orders
      where OrderDate >= @p__linq__0
      and OrderDate <= @p__linq__1
      order by OrderDate;
select top 3 OrderDate
      from Orders
      where OrderDate >= @p2
      and OrderDate <= @p3
      order by OrderDate;
select top 3 OrderDate
      from Orders
      where OrderDate >= @p4
      and OrderDate <= @p5
      order by OrderDate;',
    N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),
      @p2 datetime2(7),@p3 datetime2(7),@p4 date,@p5 date',
    @p__linq__0='2013-11-01T04:00:00',
    @p__linq__1='2013-11-30T05:00:00',
    @p2='2013-11-01T00:00:00', -- note no time
    @p3='2013-11-30T00:00:00', -- note no time
    @p4='2013-11-01',
    @p5='2013-11-30';
```

Results:

```
OrderDate
----------
2013-11-02
2013-11-02
2013-11-02

OrderDate
----------
2013-11-01
2013-11-01
2013-11-01

OrderDate
----------
2013-11-01
2013-11-01
2013-11-01
```

Comment: switching this to the correct answer.  Datatype precedence is the real explanation.

Comment: To answer your question about why the parameters have time values, it's because the query is generated by linq to entities.  The Order model class has OrderDate as a C# DateTime and the EF query uses C# DateTimes in the where clause.

Comment: Why doesn't the model class have DATE since that is the data type? Does EF really not let you use types other than those exposed by the model? Can't you write the query yourself in cases where those don't match? Every time I see a question on here that involves yet another limitation that EF places on you, I have to wonder how much time is really saved using this in the first place...

Answer (score 4):

I bet the column `OrderDate` is of type `date`, not `datetime`.
So when you do this

```
where OrderDate >= '2013-11-01 04:00'
```

it converts `'2013-11-01 04:00'` to `date`, not `datetime`, and so it loses the time information. Therefore, the condition in the first query is interpreted as `'2013-11-01 00:00:00' >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00'`. Which is true.

In the second query, the SP receives a parameter of type `datetime`, which has the time information. The condition there is interpreted as `'2013-11-01 00:00:00' >= '2013-11-01 04:00:00'` which is false.

If you want the same behavior in the first query, use a `datetime` variable instead of a string.

```
declare @d1 datetime
declare @d2 datetime
set @d1 = '2013-11-01 04:00'
set @d2 = '2013-11-30 05:00'

select top 3 OrderDate
from Orders
where OrderDate >= @d1
and OrderDate <= @d2
order by OrderDate
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand It answers the question as to why the results are different - in query1 the time is being truncated, in query2 it isn't.  It doesn't answer why query2 isn't truncating the time (but I'm guessing it's because query2 is converting the date to a datetime instead of vice versa).

Comment: The original answer, before you modified it, didn't really address the actual problem directly, it just explained why the first version of the query worked. Also, why would you suggest `DATETIME` parameters when the underlying data type is `DATE`? And why would you keep including time in the parameter values? So confusing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The question is "why is it working this way?". I simply explained him why the first query returns different results than the second. And I didn't suggest he should use `datetime` parameters. It was just a way to replicate the results from the second query in a `select` instead of a `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0_R datetime2(7) = '2013-11-01T04:00:00'
DECLARE @p__linq__1_R datetime2(7) = '2013-11-30T05:00:00'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql =  N'select top 3 OrderDate
      from Orders
      where OrderDate >= @p__linq__0_s
      and OrderDate <= @p__linq__1_s
      order by OrderDate'

exec sp_executesql @sql,
    N'@p__linq__0_s datetime2(7),@p__linq__1_s datetime2(7)',
    @p__linq__0_s =@p__linq__0_R,
    @p__linq__1_s=@p__linq__1_R
```

**Edit**
If your column is just Datetime and not Datetime2 then sql server is doing an implicit conversion on your column with Datetime datatype since Datetime2 is a higher precedence datatype then datetime. to compare two values Sql server expectes values to be in same datatype. Maybe this is what causing issues. a way around will be you can CAST the datetime column to datetime2 when comparing values.

Comment: This still gives 2013-11-02 as the first result.

Comment: What datatype your datetime column is ?

Comment: OrderDate column is of type Date.